# Match dictionary by a filter (other dictionary)

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is my dict var and a filter;

```
dict = {'company': 'Ferrari', 'model': 'Asd car', 'price': 50, color: 'red'}

filter = {'company': 'Ferrari', price:50}
```

In my filter I can add they key:value as I want for filtering.

I want to create a filter, where I can increse my filter variables for filtering for avoiding creating an incremental code, as the following one:

```
if dict['company'] == filter['company']
```

How can I get all the data matching by the keys of my filter and those values?

OUTPUT WILL BE:

```
dict1 = {'company': 'Ferrari', 'model': 'Asd car', 'price': 50, color: 'red'}
dict2 = {'company': 'Renault', 'model': 'Asd car', 'price': 50, color: 'red'}

filter = {'company': 'Ferrari', price:50}

OUTPUT = {'company': 'Ferrari', 'model': 'Asd car', 'price': 50, color: 'red'}
```

Only the first one pass, **dict1**, as it pass the filter.
The second one, **dict2** doesn't pass and the filter for company is not 'Ferrari'
I want to get the dict which pass the filter.

Comment: It is not clear how the input and outpur really look like.

Comment: Do you want to check if the filter key exists in the dict or increase your filter dict with new elements?

Comment: @SvenKrüger I updated with an example

Comment: @user5173426 I updated with an example

Comment: That is an illegal syntax, trying to squeeze the soul out of dict in python.

Comment: @user5173426 yes, you are right, sorry, there you have the correct way.

Comment: can you comment my answer? is it working for you or not? if not why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hopefully this is what you want

```
setf = set(myfilter.items()) # save space
if setf == (set(mydict.items()) & setf): # if pass 
    print(mydict) # do your stuff here
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have one question more, if I have a field such as 'model':['type1',type2'] when I am using your function I doesn't match as there is a list inside it, any idea?

Comment: cast your list to tuples.  [] to ().

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
sentinel = object()
if all(dict.get(k, sentinel) == v for k, v in filter.items()):
```

Comment: Or without the sentinel: `k in dict and dict[k] == v` (IMHO its a bit clearer that way)

Comment: It does twice the lookups.

Comment: Well, that's kind of true. It does twice the lookups if the element is in the dict, but then again, if it is not in the dict, it only does one lookup whereas yours does the lookup and then a comparison. Either one might be faster. My only (entirely subjective) point was that it might be more readable that way.

Comment: Just tried `%timeit` with two random dicts (500 items each, ~250 overlapping keys, 30 of those with equal values), and just getting the number of matching entries with `sum`, not stopping early with `all`, this showed my version to be a little bit faster (42µs vs. 72µs), but again, that was not my point, and it may very much depend on the actual dictionaries.

Comment: I suppose the mix of dictionaries is important and there are many ways to do this but thanks for those numbers, I didn't expect comparison to be much more expensive than a lookup.

Comment: To be fair, when using `all` yours probably is faster, since there can be at most one case of non-matching elements, where my approach would be faster. Did not test this, though.