# Filter a dictionary of dictionaries by another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

I have tried this answer  for my problem:
[Match dictionary by a filter (other dictionary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54806810/match-dictionary-by-a-filter-other-dictionary)

Here is the code I use :

```
    
mydict = {'foo' : 'bar', 'foo1' : {"sub_foo" : 'sub_bar', "sub_foo1" : "sub_bar1"}}

myfilter = {'foo1' : {"sub_foo" : "sub_bar"}}


setf = set(myfilter.items()) # save space
if setf == (set(mydict.items()) & setf): # if pass 
    print(mydict)
```

I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\XXX\simple_test.py", line 29, in <module>
    setf = set(myfilter.items()) # save space
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

I would like to have a way to tell if the filter `sub_dict` is included in the `dict`.

Comment: what output do you want to get?

Comment: Something that indicates that the filter is included, could be a bool, an int or return the dict itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could traverse `myfilter` and check if a value in it is a subset of the value with the same key in `mydict`:

```
for k1, v1 in myfilter.items():
    if isinstance(v1, dict):
        print(set(v1.items()).issubset(mydict.get(k1, {}).items()))
    elif isinstance(v1, (str, int, float)):
        print(v1 in mydict.get(k1, {}))
```

Output:

```
True
```

It returns True because the value under `foo1` key in `myfilter` (`{"sub_foo" : "sub_bar"}`) exists in `mydict` as the same key-value pair in `my_dict` also under `foo1` key.